# Is there a way in IntelliJ to know how much time I spend on a software project ?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am working on a Spring project using IntelliJ Idea. I want to know if there is way to know from IntelliJ logs or some other dark way, how much time I spend on this project ?

I am asking this after seeing the `Productivity Guide` from Idea. `Help > Productivity Guide`, I think could be possible, but what do you think/say/know about it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually exists such a feature 
[image]

This will however show you only the time spent working at the current task, unless you chose to do some extra [configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Time-Tracking-IDE-Integration.html)

Comment: Why did you paste the text as an image?

Comment: Because the link might become obsolete in the future